# Restoring DB using psql faster than pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm trying to speed up the process of dumping and restoring databases. At the moment, we do `pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db | psql target_db` (the DB is created before this). I read that the custom format is preferable, and I expected a binary format to be faster than a textual representation.

#### First test

```bash
hyperfine --prepare './drop_db.sh target_db ; ./create_db.sh target_db' --runs=3  -i --export-markdown report.md \
'pg_dump --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db | psql target_db'
```

| Command | Mean [s] | Min [s] | Max [s] | Relative | Resources |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `pg_dump --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 693.527 ± 5.741 | 688.635 | 699.848 | 1.03 ± 0.03 | User: 165.459 s, System: 18.331 s |
| `pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db | psql target_db` | 673.223 ± 8.535 | 663.433 | 679.100 | 1.00 | User: 12.348 s, System: 25.697 s |

→ psql is 20 s faster

#### Compression

I tested with different levels of compression because I read that compression is slow.

```bash
hyperfine --prepare './drop_db.sh target_db ; ./create_db.sh target_db' --runs=3  -i --export-markdown report.md \
'pg_dump --compress=0 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'pg_dump --compress=1 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'pg_dump --compress=5 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db | psql target_db'
```

| Command | Mean [s] | Min [s] | Max [s] | Relative | Resources |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `pg_dump --compress=0 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 702.692 ± 6.316 | 698.376 | 709.942 | 1.05 ± 0.03 | User: 18.090 s, System: 28.934 s |
| `pg_dump --compress=1 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 672.341 ± 15.539 | 655.448 | 686.025 | 1.00 | User: 89.223 s, System: 21.904 s |
| `pg_dump --compress=5 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 693.527 ± 5.741 | 688.635 | 699.848 | 1.03 ± 0.03 | User: 165.459 s, System: 18.331 s |
| `pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db | psql target_db` | 673.223 ± 8.535 | 663.433 | 679.100 | 1.00 ± 0.03 | User: 12.348 s, System: 25.697 s |

→ same performance in the best case

#### Dump / restore separated

As asked by @Bergi and @Nick I measured dumping and restoring separately.

##### Only dumping

```bash
hyperfine --runs=3 -i --export-markdown report.md \
'pg_dump --compress=0 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db > ./1' \
'pg_dump --compress=1 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db > ./2' \
'pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db > ./3'
```

| Command | Mean [s] | Min [s] | Max [s] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `pg_dump --compress=0 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db > ./1` | 77.648 ± 8.720 | 71.724 | 87.660 | 1.09 ± 0.12 |
| `pg_dump --compress=1 --no-privileges --format=custom source_db > ./2` | 104.646 ± 0.911 | 103.804 | 105.614 | 1.47 ± 0.02 |
| `pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner -w source_db > ./3` | 71.412 ± 1.037 | 70.321 | 72.385 | 1.00 |

→ psql is 7s s faster

##### Only restoring

```bash
hyperfine --prepare './drop_db.sh target_db ; ./create_db.sh target_db' --runs=3  -i --export-markdown report.md \
'cat ./1 | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'cat ./2 | pg_restore --dbname=target_db' \
'cat ./3 | psql target_db'
```

| Command | Mean [s] | Min [s] | Max [s] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `cat ./1 | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 658.715 ± 24.712 | 637.183 | 685.697 | 1.11 ± 0.04 |
| `cat ./2 | pg_restore --dbname=target_db` | 591.001 ± 8.025 | 582.334 | 598.172 | 1.00 |
| `cat ./3 | psql target_db` | 691.756 ± 15.320 | 680.285 | 709.154 | 1.17 ± 0.03 |

→ restoring is 10x slower than dumping, but is slower when separated from dumping.

---

Is there anything I can do to make this faster *without* writing the dump to disk (= using `--format=directory` which would enable parallelization)?

Comment: Try measuring the time it takes to dump and the time it takes to restore separately

Comment: Try what @Bergi said, you would get a better idea of what's going on. 

Otherwise since you are migrating the whole DB you can try using parallel processing with the -j parameter. You can find the required settings in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html and fine tune them. You might also need to apply the same for the restoration step. But custom compression formats can only be restored with pg_restore. PSQL can only restore SQL format and is far slower for production-db's in my experience.

Comment: @Nick -j is not possible, unfortunately. For `pg_dump` because _You can only use this option with the directory output format because this is the only output format where multiple processes can write their data at the same time._ and for `pg_restore` because _The input must be a regular file or directory (not, for example, a pipe or standard input)._ according to the docs.

Comment: _PSQL can only restore SQL format and is far slower for production-db's in my experience._
That what I read everywhere and that is why I'm so surprised.

Comment: "Better" does not usually mean "best at shaving a trivial amount of time off a pipeline".  It is far more flexible.  Without references to what people are saying, it is hard to know if they are talking about the same thing as you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question yourself: use

```bash
pg_dump -F c -Z 0 ... | pg_restore ...
```

That is, don't compress the dump.  If plain format dump is slightly faster for you, use that.

Since the restore is slow for you, tune the target database for that job:

- increase `max_wal_size` a lot
- increase `maintenance_work_mem` a lot
- set `wal_level = minimal` and use `--single-transaction` with `psql` or `pg_restore`, so that PostgreSQL can skip writing WAL

Comment: I already had `max_wal_size = 2GB`, `maintenance_work_mem = 2GB`. Using `--single-transaction` sped up the import tremendously! It's done in ~200s instead of 600s now.

Comment: Rejoiced to soon. With `--single-transaction` I get `ERROR:  out of shared memory You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.`. I'll investigate on Monday.

Comment: If you create a lot of objects in a single transaction, you may need a higher `max_locks_per_transaction`. That's normal.

Comment: I saved ~150s with `max_locks_per_transaction = 2000` (less was not enough) and `--single-transaction`. I'm now at 542s ± 4.5. Thank you.